# How to use IN or Nesting of queires in Eloquent ORM of Laravel 4

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I am converting my existing twitter clone toy project into Laravel 4. I have used codeigniter framework before and Eloquent ORM is the first ORM I have ever touched.
So I have confusion about how to do some advance queries,
Following query Is to fetch all the `posts` which are created by `users` who are being followed by `current_user`. This Stored procedure snippet works fine.

```
BEGIN
SELECT 
      tbl_users.id              as user_id, 
      tbl_users.display_name,
      tbl_users.username,
      tbl_posts.id              as post_id, 
      tbl_posts.post_text, 
      tbl_posts.`timestamp`
FROM tbl_posts , tbl_users
WHERE tbl_posts.user_id IN (
    SELECT tbl_followers.destination_user_id FROM tbl_followers
    WHERE  tbl_followers.source_user_id = xSource_user_id  
    )
AND tbl_posts.user_id = tbl_users.id 
ORDER BY tbl_posts.id DESC
LIMIT xLimit;

END
```

Table structure is like below :

`users` :  (id)

`posts` : (id,src_user_id [FK], post_text )

`followers` :  (id , dest_user_id [FK] , src_user_id [FK])

My best Guess is :

```
    Post::where('user_id', 'IN' , Follower::where('from_user_id','=','1'))->toSql();
```

I have added following relationships to User model

```
public function posts()
{
    return $this->hasMany('Post');
}

public function followers()
{
    return $this->hasMany('Follower');
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to use lists() to get results as array

```
    Post::whereIn('user_id', Follower::where('from_user_id','=','1')->lists('id'))->toSql();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use IN in this way:

```
Post::whereIn('user_id', yourArray)->get();
```

But I suggest you to take a look at eloquent manual [here](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent), especially the relationships part

Comment: Thanks, Not sure how to do the array thing though.

Comment: Did u created Post class?